# Numpy: frequency array to distribution

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, frequency

In python with numpy what is the fastest way to turn an array like

```
array([0,2,3,1,0,0,1])
```

into another array

```
array([1,1,2,2,2,3,6])
```

where the first array gives the frequency of each index (i.e. index 0 has a frequency of 0, index 1 has a frequency of 2, index 2 has a frequency of 3, and so on) and the second repeats each index as many times as specified in the first array.

**Background:** I use this to 'enflate' (I can't find any better word for it) a `k` by `k` Matrix `M` (sparse or not) given a length `k` frequency vector `f`:

```
f  = np.array([0,2,3,1,0,0,1])
f_ = np.array([1,1,2,2,2,3,6])
M_ = M[f_[:,None],f_]
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by your last sentence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`np.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) on the range array covering the length of the input array with the array itself for the count of repetitions -

```
np.repeat(np.arange(len(a)), a)
```

Sample run -

```
In [109]: a
Out[109]: array([0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1])

In [110]: np.repeat(np.arange(len(a)), a)
Out[110]: array([1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 6])
```